# cant define a const constructor for a class with non final fields Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to render a widget with flutter and I am getting the following errors:

"can't define a const constructor for a class with non final fields"

"constant constructor can't call non-constant super constructor of State"

"The name parameter 'Key' ins't defined"

The code with this errors is the following:

```
class ContainerButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ContainerButtonState createState() => ContainerButtonState();
}

class ContainerButtonState extends State<ContainerButton> {
  final ButtonType buttonType;
  const CustomButton({Key key, this.buttonType}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(21),
      color: Color(0xfff4f5f9),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: CustomButton(buttonType: ButtonType.download),
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: CustomButton(buttonType: ButtonType.share),
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: CustomButton(buttonType: ButtonType.problem),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I would appreciate any hint. Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `const CustomButton({Key key, this.buttonType})` with `const ContainerButton({Key key, this.buttonType})` And you have to place it outside the statefull class

Here is the final code :

```
class ContainerButton extends StatefulWidget {
   final ButtonType buttonType;
  const ContainerButton({Key key, this.buttonType}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  ContainerButtonState createState() => ContainerButtonState();
}

class ContainerButtonState extends State<ContainerButton> {
 
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(21),
        color: Color(0xfff4f5f9),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              child: CustomButton(buttonType: ButtonType.download),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: CustomButton(buttonType: ButtonType.share),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: CustomButton(buttonType: ButtonType.problem),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 14):

According to error, just remove the `const` keyword from Constructor and you are good to go. The Following code should remove the error :

```
class ContainerButtonState extends State<ContainerButton> {
  final ButtonType buttonType;
  CustomButton({Key key, this.buttonType}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(21),
      color: Color(0xfff4f5f9),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: CustomButton(buttonType: ButtonType.download),
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: CustomButton(buttonType: ButtonType.share),
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: CustomButton(buttonType: ButtonType.problem),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what if I want to use this widget in home widget (main class)  home: Login(), for example. the error will be annot invoke a non-'const' constructor where a const expression is expected.
Try using a constructor or factory that is 'const'

Answer (score 9):

> *can't define a const constructor for a class with non final fields*

`const` constructors are used so that the class attributes do not change. By not adding the `final` you are allowing that variable to change after declaration.

> *constant constructor can't call non-constant super constructor of State*

In this case, the class `State` does not have a `const` constructor (see the [api](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html)). Extending a class that does not have a `const` constructor does not allow the class extending it to have a `const` constructor.

When talking about inheritance in Dart, you can only make extending classes less restrictive but not more. If you were to make a `const` constructor, you would make the class `ContainerButtonState` more restrictive than the `State<T>` class. If you want to learn more about Dart's inheritance, here you have the [api](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#extending-a-class).

I hope I've been clear!

Comment: Thanks, man. None of the other answers explained upon this topic. I was looking for the explanation.

Answer (score 6):

**----- QUICK SOLUTION -----**

remove "const" keyword from

```
const CustomButton({Key key, this.buttonType}) : super(key: key);
```

so this would look like

```
CustomButton({Key key, this.buttonType}) : super(key: key);
```

**---- DETAILED ANSWER -----**

let's break down the question

**`const constructor`** means the constructor for which you **can't change value**

**`final`** means single-assignment: a final variable or field must have an initializer. Once assigned a value, a final variable's **value cannot be changed**

**`non final fields`** are something that you want to change in the future. like your counter(that increase by one or any you want).

**The Problem in Your code is HERE**

**`const CustomButton({Key key, this.buttonType}) : super(key: key);`**

remove "const" keyword from

```
const CustomButton({Key key, this.buttonType}) : super(key: key);
```

**MODIFIED CODE**

```
class ContainerButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ContainerButtonState createState() => ContainerButtonState();
}

class ContainerButtonState extends State<ContainerButton> {
  final ButtonType buttonType;
  CustomButton({Key key, this.buttonType}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(21),
      color: Color(0xfff4f5f9),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: CustomButton(buttonType: ButtonType.download),
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: CustomButton(buttonType: ButtonType.share),
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: CustomButton(buttonType: ButtonType.problem),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```